# Bar chart using .csv and d3.js

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, visualization

I have this data in .csv file:

```
"KWh by person/index","2005","2006","2007","2008","2009","2010","2011","2012","2013","2014","2015"
```

"kWh/person",1466.7,1493.9,1486.3,1531.2,1609.1,1573.3,1625.0,1583.0,1485.0,1473.3,1517.7

I need to create bar chart with x values "KWh by person / index" and y values "Kwh/person". I don't know how to get and use data given in this form. Please give me some suggestion. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try using d3.csv instead of the more common d3.json. Here are two links that should get you started.

https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/CSV.md

http://learnjsdata.com/read_data.html

This will convert your CSV data into a json object you can use going forward.

Answer (score -1):

Please visit: http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/3HL4a/13/

You need to return json like `[{ key: 2005, value: 1466.7 },]`